# When making a request to the Vision API Product Search an error occurs "message": "The request is missing a valid API key."

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-product-search

When I register a service account for the Vision API Product Search there's a json file downloaded into my desktop that has the private key. However, when making a request into this api there's no place to send that JSON. I'll show you the documentation and my code.
I didn't understand also what is the curl request and how to send it using the http post request.
[image: Documentation Image]

And This is my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFbYl.png):

```dart
Future<void> uploadProductSet() async {
    var projectId = 'estoOne';
    var locationId = 'europe-west1';
    var url = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$projectId/locations/$locationId/productSets';

    final responseOne = await http
        .post(Uri.parse(url),
            body: json.encode({
                'displayName': 'Product-Set-One',
            }))
        .catchError((error) {
            throw error;
    });
    print(resoinseOne.body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send your access token with the `Authorization` header.
The API seems to use the `Bearer` authentication method.

So set the following header in your http request: `Bearer $authToken`
You should get the auth-token from the credentials file you've downloaded

So your code should look something like this: (untested)

```dart
await http.post(Uri.parse(url), 
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer $authToken' },
    body: json.encode({
        'displayName': 'Product-Set-One',
})).catchError((error) {
    throw error
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how to get the credentials into the flutter project ? and how to send it with the request !

Comment: You have to read the JSON file, parse it and then insert the authtoken like in the example I gave you. Just because you have the file, doesn't mean that you have to always send everything on every request. The less you send the better, it will be faster. Just be careful that you don't store your authToken in the app of the enduser.